How to appendChild() to the BEGINNING of $node's children?
$ man XML::LibXML::Node
  appendChild
     $childnode = $node->appendChild( $childnode );

   The function will add the $childnode
   to the end of $node's children.

OK that's great. But how do I instead "add the $childnode to the BEGINNING of $node's children"?
(No blabbersome examples from me today. All I did was just change one
word. The astute reader understands the original man page. So they
also will understand when I just change one word.)
How to insert the same element on beginning and on the end of the list with insertBefore and appendChild? is for JavaScript, not LIBXML.

what about:
use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->new()->parse_string('<root><child1/><child2/></root>');
my $root = $doc->documentElement;

# Create a new child node to insert
my $new_node = XML::LibXML::Element->new('newChild');

# Check if the root has any children
if ($root->hasChildNodes()) {
    # Insert the new node before the first child
    $root->insertBefore($new_node, $root->firstChild);
} else {
    # If no children, just append as the only child
    $root->appendChild($new_node);
}

# Output the updated document
print $doc->toString(1);


